# When you define algebraic Data Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, show

Why is it a good idea to put deriving Read, Show underneath and what do they do?

Answer (score 5):

When you define your own data types, often there's a lot of boilerplate code for typeclasses that you don't really want to have to write yourself.  The compiler can often figure this out for you.

For example, if you had the type

```
data Direction = North | South | East | West
```

You wouldn't be able to do

```
if direction == North then ...
```

because you haven't written the instance of `Eq` for `Direction`.  You could write

```
instance Eq Direction where
    North == North = True
    South == South = True
    East  == East  = True
    West  == West  = True
    _     == _     = False
```

but that's 6 extra lines of code that really don't help your or someone else understand your code.  The same goes with classes like `Show`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Read`, and `Functor`, these all take up precious time and energy to write when it's pretty trivial for the compiler to figure it out all by itself.  That's where the `deriving` clause comes in.  All of the type classes I've mentioned are derivable (although `Functor` needs the `DeriveFunctor` extension in GHC), and there's a handful of others.  All it does is instruct the compiler to figure out the implementations for these typeclasses itself, so

```
data Direction = North | South | East | West
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Show, Read)
```

will generate a lot of code that you *could* write yourself, but isn't much fun to do so.  You can see the code that gets generated by compiling with the `-ddump-deriv` flag, if you want, but it won't be very pretty since it's compiler generated.

Answer (score 2):

Instance deriving is a powerful feature in Haskell which has the compiler automatically create reasonable instances of some typeclasses for types you create. Oftentimes there are reasonable default instances for things like `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show`, `Read`, `Enum`, and `Bounded` which the compiler can just guess. For instance, `Eq` on a finite sum type.

```
data Sum = A | B | C deriving ( Eq )

-- is equivalent to
instance Eq Sum where
  A == A = True
  B == B = True
  C == C = True
  _ == _ = False
```

Deriving thus cuts down on a lot of boilerplate when it's appropriate. Altogether deriving is considered to be a core feature of Haskell and it has both been extended by compiler extensions like `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, `DeriveFunctor`, `DeriveFoldable`, `DeriveTraversable`, `DeriveGeneric`, and `DeriveDataTypeable` and embraced by the community using `Generics` deriving and `TemplateHaskell` automatically generated instances.

For instance, if you use the `aeson` Haskell-JSON data binding library you'll often see the Template Haskell

```
deriveJSON ''MyType
```

which automatically creates instances for both `ToJSON` and `FromJSON`.

Taken together, these are all methods to ensure that only the most important and specific parts of your code have to be written. Derived instances tend to be the "simplest possible instances" and thus have the least surprising behavior possible. Small deviations from these defaults can be coded more directly after they form the base layer of functionality.

Comment: You forget DeriveGeneric

Comment: Yup—I've added it now!

Answer (score 1):

`Read`, `Show`, `Eq` and friends are typeclasses. Basically they're interfaces that can make certain functions, like `show`, `read`, `==` and others work for your type. The two that you mentioned, `Show` and `Read` define two functions on your type.

```
read :: String -> YourType
show :: YourType -> String
```

In fact, what it actually does is generate a typeclass instance that lets you use `read` and `show` as if they had these types.

It's often nice to just let `deriving` take care of this since it's just boilerplate, often for debugging. Often you just want to print stuff out and `deriving Show` gives you a nice quick way to do that.

In essence, `deriving` is just a way to get the compiler to generate code for you. This is especially helpful with `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Bounded` where you could easily make a trivial mistake that would be very very hard to debug.